# What is meant by the "functoriality of the adjoint representation"?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Just a simply question.  I came across the following statement which is used for deriving Weyl's integral formula:

''$\text{Ad}_G(h)|_{\mathfrak{h}} = \text{Ad}_H(h)$ due to functoriality in the Lie group for the adjoint representation''.

Therefore we have $\text{Ad}_G(t_0^{-1})$ mod $\mathfrak{t}$ = Ad$_{G/T}(t_0^{-1})$.

Could somebody define for me the ''functoriality'' in the context of adjoint representation?

Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is meant here is that the adjoint representation is nicely compatible with homomorphisms of Lie groups. For a homomorphism $\phi:H\to G$, let $\phi':\mathfrak h\to\mathfrak g$ be the derivative. Then it is a basic fact of Lie theory that $\phi(exp(tX))=\exp(t\phi'(X))$ for all $X\in\mathfrak h$. Now for $h\in H$ and $X\in\mathfrak h$, you get Ad$(h)(X)$ as the derivative at $t=0$ of the curve $h\exp(tX)h^{-1}$. Using the above fact, you get $\phi(h\exp(tX)h^{-1})=\phi(h)\exp(t\phi'(X))\phi(h)^{-1}$. Differentiating at $t=0$, we obtain $\phi'(Ad(h)(X))=Ad(\phi(h))(\phi'(X))$, which is the functorial property the argument refers to. You just have to apply this to the inclusion $i:H\to G$ whose derivative $i'$ is the inclusion $\mathfrak h\hookrightarrow\mathfrak g$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas!  That is very clear explanation!  But it seems like it is better called the consequence of the local diffeomorphism property of exponential map!

Comment: The result certainly is a consequence of the fact that the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism, but this is true for large parts of Lie theory. It really is the compatibility of the adjoint representation with homomorphisms.

Comment: Got you Andreas!  You are emphasizing the compatibility of the adjoint representation with homomorphisms over the local diffeomorphism property of the exponential map.